# c# - Ninject with Automapper in class library

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-6, automapper, ninject

I organize my project into class libraries and a main caller (now is a console application, then will Apis).

- DAL library
- BL library
- Models (entity) library
- Main (console application)

I added Automapper and configured it to work between DAL and BL (Models rapresents all the entity that exposes the BL layer as point in common with other projects).
That's good, but i decided to inject a IMapper via an IoC Container so i can pass the interface to constructors. 
Keeping in mind my architecture how can i configure Ninject for this purpose?

I'm using Automapper with "Api Instance" like this:

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {
    cfg.AddProfile<AppProfile>();
    cfg.CreateMap<Source, Dest>();
});


var mapper = config.CreateMapper();
```

Thanks

SOLUTION:

In the Business Logic layer i added a Ninject module:

```
    public class AutomapperModule : NinjectModule
    {
        public StandardKernel Nut { get; set; }

        public override void Load()
        {
            Nut = new StandardKernel(); 
            var mapperConfiguration = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => { CreateConfiguration(); });
            Nut.Bind<IMapper>().ToConstructor(c => new AutoMapper.Mapper(mapperConfiguration)).InSingletonScope(); 
        }


        public IMapper GetMapper()
        {
            return Nut.Get<IMapper>();
        }

        private MapperConfiguration CreateConfiguration()
        {
            var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
            {
                cfg.AddProfiles(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
                cfg.AddProfiles(Assembly.Load("DataAccess"));
            });

            return config;
        }
    }
```

It's a mix between the examples on AutoMapper site and the answer of Jan Muncinsky.

I also added a Get method for returing the context mapper, just for helper.
The client just have to call something like this:

```
var ioc = new AutomapperModule();
ioc.Load();
var mapper = ioc.GetMapper();
```

in then passing mapper to constructors...

If you have a better solution feel free to post.

Comment: http://automapperdocs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Dependency-injection.html

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu, i have seen that doc, but it's not very clear for me. For example the difference between AutoMapperModule and Register.

Comment: Just to clarify, normally you don't create kernel inside of module. But you create kernel first and configure kernel with module. See my edited answer how to use Ninject modules properly. Also `Get<IMapper>()` is only for a demonstration purpose, most probably you'll use this method only for resolving the root object of your object graph and `IMapper` will be passed to constructors by Ninject automatically. So there is no need to pass something manually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the simplest form it's easy as:

```
var kernel = new StandardKernel();
var mapperConfiguration = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => { cfg.AddProfile<AppProfile>(); });
kernel.Bind<IMapper>().ToConstructor(c => new Mapper(mapperConfiguration)).InSingletonScope();

var mapper = kernel.Get<IMapper>();
```

With usage of Ninject modules:

```
public class AutoMapperModule : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        var mapperConfiguration = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => { cfg.AddProfile<AppProfile>(); });
        this.Bind<IMapper>().ToConstructor(c => new Mapper(mapperConfiguration)).InSingletonScope();
        this.Bind<Root>().ToSelf().InSingletonScope();
    }
}

public class Root
{
    public Root(IMapper mapper)
    {
    }
}
```

...

```
var kernel = new StandardKernel(new AutoMapperModule());
var root = kernel.Get<Root>();
```

Comment: Thanks Jan, do you mean all the classes should inherit from Root class? AutoMapperModule is placed in client or in library, for you? Could you, please, put a little example in what you put in class library and client (webapi, console app)? I can't figure how the mapper is injected automatically. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @MaxBertoli, No, `Root` is just an example of some class that depends on `IMapper`, it can be a controller as well in case you use webapi. In case of web.api you will use Ninject extensions for web and your controllers are created by Ninject and all their dependencies as well. In case of console app it deppends what you need to do, but probably you will resolve some root object. `AutoMapperModule` is a part of your composition root.